# Read CSV file and replace accented characters using PHP

Tags: php, csv, for-loop, while-loop, str-replace

I have a CSV file with data inside. The CSV file is comma delimited. It contains characters which are accented. I want to be able to sanitize the file to replace all accented characters with their English equivalent.

I am reading the file in using PHP and I have a function to replace accented characters. However, I cannot seem to get the function to work.

**Reading in CSV file.**

```
$row = 1;
if ( ( $handle = fopen( $input_filename , "r" ) ) !== FALSE ) {

    while( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle, 1000, "," ) ) !== FALSE ) {

        $num = count( $data );

        $row++;

        for ( $c=0; $c < $num; $c++ ) {

            echo replaceAccents( $data[$c] )."\n";

        }

    }

    fclose( $handle );
}
```

**Replacing Accents function**

```
function replaceAccents($str) {

  $search = explode(",","ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,ø,Ø,Å,Á,À,Â,Ä,È,É,Ê,Ë,Í,Î,Ï,Ì,Ò,Ó,Ô,Ö,Ú,Ù,Û,Ü,Ÿ,Ç,Æ,Œ");

  $replace = explode(",","c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,o,O,A,A,A,A,A,E,E,E,E,I,I,I,I,O,O,O,O,U,U,U,U,Y,C,AE,OE");

  return str_replace($search, $replace, $str);


}
```

When I run the program, it still seems to echo out the accented characters.

How can I read in the file in, replace the accented characters, and output the sanitized file back out?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your function, but you can also use [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to get the results you are looking for.

Just replace:

```
echo replaceAccents( $data[$c] )."\n";
```

with:

```
echo iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT', $data[$c]) . "\n";
```

[An example using your data](https://eval.in/864072).

Comment: This removed everything after and including the accented characters, it does not replace it?

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji It shouldn't: https://eval.in/864076. What does your code look like and what are the contents of the variables?